# Data not Saved in file xml

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-xml

I have this code in ASP.NET MVC: I want to save the data from datareader in xml file I used this code shown below but I have in the file just two lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Centre_Commercial />
```

My code in the controller:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
XElement nodecentre = new XElement("Centre_Commercial");
document.Add(nodecentre);

while (dr.Read())
{
    nodecentre.Add(new XElement("Num_Centre", Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString())));
    nodecentre.Add(new XElement("Num_Centre", dr[1].ToString()));
    nodecentre.Add(new XElement("Num_Centre", Convert.ToDateTime(dr[2].ToString()).Date));
    nodecentre.Add(new XElement("Num_Centre", int.Parse(dr[3].ToString())));
    nodecentre.Add(new XElement("Num_Centre", int.Parse(dr[4].ToString())));
    nodecentre.Add(new XElement("Num_Centre", Convert.ToDateTime(dr[5].ToString())));
    nodecentre.Add(new XElement("Num_Centre", dr[6].ToString()));
    nodecentre.Add(new XElement("Num_Centre", dr[7].ToString()));
    nodecentre.Add(new XElement("Num_Centre", int.Parse(dr[8].ToString())));

    document.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/test.Xml"));
}

con.Close();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kamilia, please update your original post and add there a desired XML output.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky i want from the data Get all data in file xml i get just two line? in above the script

Comment: Kamilia, I understand what is happening. Please share your desired **output XML**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `.Save(...)` method call out of the loop.

> c#

```
}
con.Close();
document.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/test.Xml"));
```

> SQL

Very possible that you need to add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as a first line in the stored procedure.

```
create procedure spBudget
(
    @budget1 int,
    @budget2 int
) as 
begin 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select * from Centre_Commercial where budget between @b and @b;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

MS SQL Server will generate/shape XML based on the desired output. It is a regular `SELECT ...` statement with the additional `FOR XML` clause. I am using dynamic SQL because I don't have your database, and I don't know your desired output XML.

(1) You would need just slightly modify the `SqlCommand` variable to accommodate your stored procedure with parameters. (2) Your stored procedure would need to add `FOR XML` clause.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\temp\file2.xml";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=pubs;Data Source=SPACESHIP"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP(2) * FROM dbo.authors FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')";
        con.Open();

        using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
            settings.IndentChars = "\t";
            // to remove BOM
            settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings))
            {
                xdoc.Save(writer);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("File '{0}' has been created.", FILENAME);
    }
}
```

> Output XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <r>
      <au_id>172-32-1176</au_id>
      <au_lname>White</au_lname>
      <au_fname>Johnson</au_fname>
      <phone>408 496-7223</phone>
      <address>10932 Bigge Rd.</address>
      <city>Menlo Park</city>
      <state>CA</state>
      <zip>94025</zip>
      <contract>1</contract>
   </r>
   <r>
      <au_id>213-46-8915</au_id>
      <au_lname>Green</au_lname>
      <au_fname>Marjorie</au_fname>
      <phone>415 986-7020</phone>
      <address>309 63rd St. #411</address>
      <city>Oakland</city>
      <state>CA</state>
      <zip>94618</zip>
      <contract>1</contract>
   </r>
</root>
```

Comment: I get with the test of  function only return the of the function:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ControlWCSNew.Models.Centre_Commercial]

Comment: Kamilia, I gave you a minimal reproducible example. Run it, learn from it, and apply to your exact scenario. Also, please connect with me on LinkedIn.